# Getting SecurityException when deserializing object despite using AllPermission java policy

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

In my XPages application, I backup certain objects by serializing and saving them to MIME entities in backup documents. To reload the objects later, I use the following server-side JavaScript function for deserialization:

```
var entity:NotesMIMEEntity=doc.getMIMEEntity(field);
if (!entity) return null;
var stream:NotesStream=session.createStream();
entity.getContentAsBytes(stream);
stream.setPosition(0);
var ois:java.io.ObjectInputStream=new java.io.ObjectInputStream(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(stream.read()));
var o=ois.readObject(); // ERROR OCCURS IN THIS LINE
ois.close();
entity.recycle();
doc.closeMIMEEntities(false,field);
```

When I try to read the object from the stream, an exception is raised:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Java bridge is not allowed

I have set the **java.security.AllPermission** in the java.policy file, so I don't know why this exception is raised anyway. I also found that this problem only occurs when I run my application in the **Notes Client**, but everything works fine when I run it in the browser via the Domino server.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue?

PS: Here is the full trace for the SecurityException:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Java bridge is not allowed
at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSUtility.wrapAsObject(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSUtility.wrap(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSValue.readValue(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSDefaultObject.readExternal(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.ObjectObject.readExternal(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTForIn.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTUnaryOp.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.initBeforePageContents(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.addComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIIncludeComposite.buildContents(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildChildren(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledComponentBuilder.buildAll(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.buildContents(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx2.buildContents(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.initComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createTree(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.AbstractCompiledPage.createViewRoot(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.access$0(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceRequest.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService$NsfServiceThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this in Domino 9.0.x?

In XPiNC the Java security settings are not managed by the server but on the relevant Notes Client. In the User Security settings, on the **What Others Do > Using Workstation** tab, for each signer a check box was added in R9 for "Load Java Code". This needs to be ticked for the signer of the XPiNC application.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, it is Domino 9.0.1 and "Load Java Code" is checked. I now also checked it for all other users in the list and again signed the whole application design with my ID. It is still not working, but I recognized something else: When I freshly start the Notes Client and open my applcation, everything works fine. As soon as I open my application in the Designer and build it, the next time I run it in the Notes Client I get the SecurityException described above. Do you have another idea what the problem could be?

Comment: That's a known issue with XPiNC development. If you build the application in Designer, close Notes and re-open it or you are not likely to get consistent behaviour. Designer build creates .java files for XPages and Custom Controls in Local folder, which is outside the NSF. These get compiled down to byte code. Notes effectively mimics the server, so I suspect it caches the .class files which may or may not get stored to the same location.

Comment: I know there are similar caching issues with Single Copy XPage Design and OSGi plugins, where you need to restart HTTP, which is effectively the same as closing and restarting Notes. I suspect XPiNC works similarly, so you need to "restart the local XPiNC runtime", effectively done by closing and restarting Notes. There may be a workaround, if anyone knows of a way to restart the XPiNC runtime, but I'm not aware of where that's handled.

Comment: Thanks for all the information. I'll keep digging and report here in case I find a solution.